# Empty WebBrowser with no background in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm facing a strange issue. I've add into my VB application a WebBrowser without made any further change on it. And when I run it in order to display a web page like "www.google.com", instead of the white background, I can see the window behind. It's just like the white color is fully transparent. I've try to add a screenshot to this topic but I don't have enough "reputation" yet.

How can I remove this opacity behavior and have the default white background ? Do I need to initialize the webBrowser with white background color ?

Thank you.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've most likely accidentally set the TransparencyKey() of the Form to White.  Clear that field and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I've finally created a new project and the problem did not appears. So as you said, I might "accidentally" change a parameter. Thank for your support.